# How to update photos in elementary OS Freya?

Tags: updates, photos

I'm trying to update Photo (shotwell) from 0.1 to 0.22.0 but don't let me do that... incompatible version of libGphoto.

I appreciate a good update for photos, because is too much unstable.

So I have two questions
How to update photos? 
There is an major update from elementary OS?

Good Luck!!

Comment: I have reverted my edit :)

Comment: Coudl you please provide more information, e.g. detailed error message, please?

Comment: ravan, thanks!
@bigbang yes, I download the sourcecode from gnome webpage and do this:
>    ~>./configure
>    No compatible libGPhoto installation found. Configuration cannot continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advisable to upgrade photos because, it may leads to incompatible issues. The reason is Shotwell 0.1.1 is based on schema 21 where as the version is 0.18 (or other) based on schema 20.

But even you can view/open photos (images) from shotwell

If still want latest version:

From the output of `apt-cache policy shotwell`:

```
ravan@ravan:~$ apt-cache policy shotwell
shotwell:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 0.18.0-0ubuntu4
```

The available version is: **0.18**.

You can install with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install shotwell-common # to satisfy dependency in my case
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

The available version via ppa: **0.20**

To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

**Note**: shotwell **0.22** is not available for freya at present, see [here](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty)

Comment: If you dont like my question, erase it.

Comment: @koxmoz I am sorry, If you are not comfortable with my edit, please feel free to roll back :)

Answer (score 1):

Photos is the "The elementary continuation of Shotwell", so I think it is advisable to stick with it. Besides that, shotwell 0.22 can be installed only on Ubuntu 14.10+ while freya is based on 14.04.